# Apache URL rewrite ignored for a subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'd like to publish a maintenance message for one of the subdirectories on my domain. This code is placed in the /.htaccess of the domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/webmail/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/webmail-maintenance.html -f
RewriteRule $ /webmail-maintenance.html [L]
```

If webmail-maintenance.html exists in the root directory, it should be served for whatever was requested from the webmail directory. It has no effect though. If I replace the first line with another directory name, like test, and create a new directory named test with a single index.html in it, the above configuration has the desired effect. It just doesn't work for the webmail directory.

There is another .htaccess file in the webmail directory, but it doesn't contain contradictory rewrite rules. [Here's its contents.](https://github.com/roundcube/roundcubemail/blob/master/.htaccess) Is rewriting not supported at all if the subdirectory contain a .htaccess file itself?

The web server is Apache 2.4 on Linux.

Comment: What happens when you go to **/webmail/** ?

Comment: I see the content in that directory, as if that configuration wasn't there at all.

Comment: Do you anyother rewriteRules in /.htaccess?

Comment: There are more RewriteRules in the root directory, but this one in my question comes first and the `[L]` should prevent any other rules after this has matched. It just doesn't match.

Comment: You are right. but I think your folder/htaccess is conflicting with the request. Does it work if you remove or rename your **/folder/.htaccess** ?

Comment: Yes, that works. So what's the problematic part of the subdirectory .htaccess file? Its content is linked in the question.

Comment: There are five sections, remove a section and test, remove the next and test again, and so on ...

Comment: It's any of the rewrite-related directives alone. As soon as one of them is there, the parent directory's rules are ignored.